# bound on $l_2$ error in approximating a vector with its $t$-sparse representation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

How do I prove that for any vector $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and any positive integer $t$, 
\begin{equation}
||y-y_t||_2\:\leq\: \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}||y||_1
\end{equation}
where $y_t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the vector consisting of the $t$ largest magnitude entries in $y$, the remaining entries being zero, i.e., $y_t$ is the $t$-sparse representation of $y$? For example, if $y=[5\: 6\: 2\: 3]^{\prime}$, then $y_2=[5\:6\:0\:0]^{\prime}$.

Comment: It will be a good idea to refer books on sparse representations and compressed sensing, for eg, Michael Elad's book is a good place to look for.

Comment: Note that, norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces.

Comment: An interesting item of note is that, for $t<n$, $n \geq 2\sqrt{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, we may assume that $y$ is entrywise nonnegative and $y^T = (x^T, z^T)$, where $0\le x_1\le x_2\le\cdots x_{n-t}\le z_1\le z_2\le\cdots\le z_t$. We want to prove that
$$\|x\|_2 \le \frac1{2\sqrt{t}} (\|x\|_1 + \|z\|_1).$$
The minimum possible value of $\|z\|_1$ is $tx_\max=tx_{n-t}$. So, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
&\|x\|_2 \le \frac1{2\sqrt{t}} (\|x\|_1 + t x_\max),\\
\text{i.e. }&q(t) := t^2 x_\max^2 + 2t (x_\max \|x\|_1 - 2 \|x\|_2^2) + \|x\|_1^2 \ge 0.
\end{align*}
If $x_\max \|x\|_1 \le 2\|x\|_2^2$, the critical point of the quadratic function $q(t)$ lies on the negative $t$-axis. Therefore $q(t)\ge q(0)\ge0$ for all $t\ge0$.

If $x_\max \|x\|_1 > 2\|x\|_2^2$, then
$(x_\max \|x\|_1 - 2 \|x\|_2^2)^2 \le x_\max^2 \|x\|_1^2$ and
$$\frac{-(x_\max \|x\|_1 - 2 \|x\|_2^2)^2}{x_\max^2} + \|x\|_1^2 \ge 0.$$
Hence the global minimum value of $q(t)$ is nonnegative. In turn, $q$ is always nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!